# Powershell script - Data not getting passed to export-csv

Tags: powershell

I'm looking up AD users based on the 'company name' field in the AD user record. I am collecting and formatting what I need (I can successfully export it to a csv file), but when I try to filter my records based on strings within the email address, I get the error "cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:"
I have to cancel the script.

I've build several Powershell scripts for looking up AD users using the old Quest cmdlets, and I am migrating to the Microsoft cmdlets.

```
    $path = "c:\users\username\desktop\data data"
    $getdom = (Get-ADForest).domains

    foreach ($domain in $getdom) {Get-ADUser -Server $domain -Filter {    company -like "company name here" }  -Properties *  | 
    Select-Object -property @{L='Agency';E={$_.Company}}, 
                            @{L='UserDN';E={$_.DistinguishedName}}, 
                            @{L='UserName';E={$_.Name}},
                            @{L='Employee ID';E={$_.employeeType}},
                            @{L='IDType';E={$_.ObjectClass}}, 
                            @{L='LogonName';E={$_.samaccountname}},
                            @{L='UPN';E={$_.userprincipalname}},
                            @{L='EMail';E={$_.EmailAddress}} | 
    #
     foreach{if($_.EMail -like "*email.domain1*") {export-csv  $path\mph\mph.mphuserinfo.csv -append -notype } `  
       elseif($_.EMail -like "*email.domain2*") {export-csv -path $path\mph\mph.ksm.userinfo.csv -append -notype }  `
         else {export-csv -path $path\mph\mph\mph.other.userinfo.csv -append -nnotype } } }
```

Im working in Powershell ISE (windows 10) and get the following results when I run the script:

```
  cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
  Supply values for the following parameters:
  InputObject: (I have to cancel the script here)
```

Comment: You are not piping any objects into `Export-Csv`. You should try piping the current pipeline object `$_` into `Export-Csv`. You can try `$_ | Export-Csv ..... `.

Comment: Thanks - that worked. I'm fairly new to Powershell.